# Delete Entire Row in Specific sheet Based on a value in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a relatively long subroutine that calls two external subs. In the sub, on one sheet=`Start`, VBA copies an account number and stores it under the variable name `Acct` (formatted as `string`). At the end of the sub, I would like VBA to activate another sheet=`Stop`, match `Acct` with a value in `Column A` (which is formatted as a *number*), then delete the **entire** row containing that number. I am just needing some assistance with finding and deleting the entire row containing that number.

It may also be worth mentioning that the numbers in column A are *not* in numerical order. Also, both sheets are located in the same workbook, we can call `WB1`.

Comment: Either `Find()` or `Match()` should do what you need.  To delete the found row: `EntireRow.Delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Match function, which will return the row number as an integer variable. Then use Rows(row number).Delete

https://mysyntaxvba.wordpress.com/2016/08/16/what-is-the-syntax-to-return-the-row-of-a-found-value/